# <rich:dataTable> header height

Tags: datatable, richfaces

Whenever I have a table header going into 3 rows, the background is not able expand. When it is only 2 rows all seems to be fine. Does anybody went through this ?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, couldn't attach image.

Image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6xNl.png

Table in xhtml

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{couponController.campaignSegmentVersionDtoList}"
var="campaignSegment" id="sas" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
styleClass="stable" style="width:1100px;" sortMode="single" rowKeyVar="myrow">
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">No</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{myrow + 1}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortBy="#{campaignSegment.segmentName}" id="segmentName">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="Campaign Segment" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('segmentName')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.segmentName}" />
</rich:column>                                  
<rich:column sortBy="#{campaignSegment.segmentTitle}" id="segmentTitle">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="MRM Segment Name" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('segmentTitle')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.segmentTitle}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortBy="#{campaignSegment.sourceCode}" id="sourceCode">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="Source Code" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('sourceCode')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.sourceCode}">
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>  
<rich:column id="packageCode" sortBy="#{campaignSegment.packageCode}" style="width:80px;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="SAS Package Code"  onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('packageCode')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.packageCode}">
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>                                  
<rich:column id="version" style="width:80px;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="MRM Version Code" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{campaignSegment.versionCode}" valueChangeListener="#{couponController.valueChangeListener}" label="Version Code" listWidth="300" immediate="true">
<f:selectItems value="#{couponController.mrmVersions}" var="version" itemLabel="#{version.versionCode}" itemValue="#{version.versionId}"/>
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="stringCodeList" execute="@this" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<rich:message for="Version"/>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="testControlFlag" sortBy="{campaignSegment.testControlFlag}" style="width:60px">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="Test Control Flag" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('testControlFlag')" style="color:white"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.testControlFlag}"/>
</rich:column>                                                                      
<rich:column sortBy="#{campaignSegment.publishedDate}" id="publishedDate">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="Published Date" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('publishedDate')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.publishedDate}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy H:m:s"/>
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>                                                          
<rich:column sortBy="#{campaignSegment.status}" sortOrder="#{couponController.campaignSegmentsDescOrder}" id="publishStatus">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <a4j:commandLink value="Publish Status" onclick="#{rich:component('sas')}.sort('publishStatus')" style="color:white;"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{campaignSegment.status}">
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
```

Comment: Add the link of the image on the text, we edit it for you… Also add your code for drawing the table.

Comment: What version of RichFaces do you use?

Comment: I am using version 4.3.5. Thank you Mackiel,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image starts repeating itself, which it shouldn't do.

You can fix that with this:

```
.rf-dt-hdr-c {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try and will post the result.

Comment: That worked with a little syntax correction. Supposed to be '.rf-dt.shdr-c'. Thank you.

Comment: There are both `hdr` and `shdr`, shdr is a subheader.

Comment: shdr is used for column header in rich:datatable. I wonder where hdr is used.

Comment: In the header of the table.